# What's the difference between “rei" (冷) and “Samui” (寒い)?

Tags: word-choice, words

What's the difference between [“rei"冷](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=rei) and [“Samui” 寒い](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=19925&j=Samui) ?

Both mean “cold”, but when would you use one over the other?

Please explain by giving reference to the below examples:

> 1. 冷凍用ビニール袋 (reitou-you Binīru fukuro)
>    Freezer bag

> 2. 寒いです ( samui desu)
>    It is cold

Comment: Were you thinking of using 冷 on its own rather than as part of an onyomi compound? This does not seem to be a common usage: https://jisho.org/search/%E5%86%B7%20(%E3%82%8C%E3%81%84) . You should think of 冷凍 as a word in its own right here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the Kanji:

- 冷 is for **objects** that are cold, such as drinks, food, or whatever *object* you can think of.
- 寒 applies to the temperature **around you** or the **atmospheric
  temperature**, not to the temperature of concrete objects.

Also take into account [user3856370's warning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/whats-the-difference-between-rei-%E5%86%B7-and-samui-%E5%AF%92%E3%81%84#comment139896_86644%3C). 冷{れい} (rei) is not a word per se but it is usually a component of other words, whereas 寒{さむ}い (samui) is an actual word meaning cold (weather-wise).

If you want to use 冷 as an adjective, as opposed to 寒{さむ}い (samui), the word would be 冷{つめ}たい (tsumetai).

Compare both adjectives in the following sample sentences:

> 今日{きょう}は寒{さむ}い ! / (kyou wa samui! ) / It's cold today!

> このビールは冷{つめ}たくて 美味{おい}しい ! / (kono biiru wa tsumetakute oishii! ) This beer is cold and tasty!